# Google Play New Console | Manage publishing

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

If a app has been approved and pending to publish using Manage publishing, how can we cancel the release?

Comment: Hello, you could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873362/how-to-update-upgrade-your-android-apk-during-staged-rollout-in-google-play/22873363#22873363

Comment: @rguzman please let me know about New Google Play console. I have not found anything related to recent changes for Console

Comment: I see, the last November 2, they update the google play console. I think, you can review https://play.google.com/console/about/ and https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859062?hl=es-419. Also the functionality is the same as the previous version.

Comment: An workaround, is to restrict the app only for specific testers and uncheck all the lists, in this way nobody can see the app in play store.

Comment: As per Google Support personnel there is no way to cancel the approved/submit release .. you have to publish it